# Force HTML5 video autoplay unmuted

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5-video, autoplay

The autoplay attribute doesn't work if the video is not muted

```
<video controls autoplay muted>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I tried this solution to unmute the video just after the video start playing but it did not work, I get this error message 'Unmuting failed and the element was paused instead because the user didn't interact with the document before'

```
$('video').on('canplay', function() {
    $(this).muted = false;
});
```

Is there any way I can force autoplay just like netflix do
https://www.netflix.com/ma-en/watch/80196789

Comment: No, there is not.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to autoplay with unmuted:

```
<video src="movie.mp4" controls autoplay></video>
```

**OR** 
`Iframe` tag can also be used:

```
<iframe src="movie.mp4"></iframe>
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a couple sources that use the autoplay and muted with the controls attribute to make it work
A website that use this code: [Autoplay HTML5 Video muted](https://walterebert.com/playground/video/autoplay/)

And I found this answer in another post maybe this works for you:
Source [[l33tstealth]](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7564143/l33tstealth)

```
<html>
<body>

<video width="320" height="240" autoplay controls muted>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The muted attribute of the video tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

</body>
</html>
```