# Youtube videos unmuted autoplay

Tags: html5-video

I read that it's not possible to start playing a video automatically in Html unless it's muted, or if the user triggers it as in a button click, etc. So how do Youtube videos start automatically and unmuted? How can I achieve the same?

Answer (score -1):

It is possible just add `?autoplay=1` to the end of the youtube video link you are embedding. First right-click on the video click copy embed info then paste it into your code then add `?autoplay=1` at the end of the link example:

(video does not work in snippit)

```html
<iframe width="676" height="380" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lUqxyLjq9SM?autoplay=1"title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" 
allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"  allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and it certainly gave me some information I was not aware of, but my question was something else. I asked how to play a video on my website automatically and unmuted. I read that it's not possible because of security reasons, but then I saw that on Youtube it is possible, so how do they do it? And can I do the same? Got it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65157672/force-html5-video-autoplay-unmuted

Comment: I did give you your answer if you add `?autoplay=1` to the end of the embedded youtube link it will autoplay unmuted.

Comment: I'm not playing a Youtube link, I'm playing my own video.

Comment: @thecocoman the **question** is not how to make a Youtube link (or `iframe`) to autoplay, the question is about how the Youtube website itself can make their video content autoplay with sound (when browsers do not allow it by design unless the video is muted). Try it yourself... Make a `<video>` tag with `autoplay` setting then check your console for the warning (and no auto-playing of the video). So how does Youtube avoid that issue?... is the question.